Asynchronous copying
When copying Prosemirror elements, I create new node elements with attributes for resources (images) in the form of base64, but before that I get them asynchronously from storage.
I convert nodes to json, example:
["{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"content\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"kh\"}]}","{\"type\":\"image\",\"attrs\":{\"src\":\"data:image/png;iVBORw0\",\"alt\":null,\"title\":null,\"crop\":{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"w\":100,\"h\":100},\"objects\":[]}}","{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"content\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"teytey\"}]}"]

And trying save to event.clipboardData.setData("text/my-app", json). But due to asynchrony, the code does not have time to write the text to the clipboard. How can I fix this?
My code:
addProseMirrorPlugins() {
        return [
            new Plugin({
                props: {
                    handleDOMEvents: {
                        copy: (view: EditorView, event: ClipboardEvent) => {
                            void copyArticleResource(view, event, this.options.apiUrlCreator, false);
                            return false;
                        },
                    },
                },
            }),
        ];
    },

const copyArticleResource = async (
    view: EditorView,
    event: ClipboardEvent,
    apiUrlCreator: ApiUrlCreator,
    isModX: boolean,
    callback?: () => void,
) => {
    const { from, to } = view.state.selection;
    const { doc } = view.state;
    const slice = doc.slice(from, to);

    const jsonText = await createNodesJSON(view, slice.content, apiUrlCreator);
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/my-app", JSON.stringify(jsonText));

    if (callback) callback();
};

I want to receive json synchronously so that I can write to clipboardData in time.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
